# Error NuGet package google translation API

Tags: nuget, asp.net-core-2.0, google-translate

I'm trying to install the Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 package from NuGet and I keep getting this error

Failed to retrieve information about 'Google.Cloud.Translation.V2' from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/google.cloud.translation.v2/index.json'.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  Unable to connect to the remote server
  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 72.21.81.200:443

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the library's version in your command like this:

```
Install-Package Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 -Version 1.1.0
```

or:

```
dotnet add package Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 --version 1.1.0
```

or:

```
paket add Google.Cloud.Translation.V2 --version 1.1.0
```

Then, a firewall may be blocking you. If you're using any of those commands and the error persists, then this is not a coding issue, this issue could be checked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) for a possible firewall blocking you or any other network issue.